# What is the proper frame size of the MPVolumeView control?

Tags: ios, mpvolumeview

When I create an MPVolumeView, what vertical dimensions should I give it for the frame/bounds?

It seems like I can give it whatever horizontal dimensions I want and it will scale properly. Is there a range of valid values for this as well?

When I try to set a UIView to be of the MPVolumeView class in Interface Builder, whenever it is drawn to the screen, it never ends up aligned vertically where I want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I was able to test it, you can make the `MPVolumeView` as big as you want and the slider somehow stays stuck on the top, not aligned. You can subclass `MPVolumeView` and implement `volumeSliderRectForBounds:` to set the slider's frame in the volume view's bounds. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20069707/645981).