# Center MPVolumeView vertically in SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uiviewrepresentable

I want to place an `MPVolumeView` in my SwiftUI view but it doesn't behave like a normal SwiftUI view. I want the volume slider to be centered vertically between the two dividers. If you replaced `VolumeSlider` with `Text` it would be centered. How can I make the `VolumeSlider` behave in the same way?

```
// Must be run on real device, not simulator

import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            VolumeSlider()
                .frame(height: 128)
            Divider()
        }
        
    }
}

struct VolumeSlider: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MPVolumeView {
        MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MPVolumeView, context: Context) {}
}
```

[image: Not centered vertically]

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue today and built a solution based off the selected answer from this post: [Matching MPVolumeView and UISlider vertical positions in a UIToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787816/matching-mpvolumeview-and-uislider-vertical-positions-in-a-uitoolbar/20778517#20778517)

The issued is resolved by overriding volumeSliderRect and routeButtonRect.

```
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer
import UIKit

struct VolumeSlider: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    class SystemVolumeView: MPVolumeView {
        
        override func volumeSliderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            var newBounds = super.volumeSliderRect(forBounds: bounds)
            newBounds.origin.y = bounds.origin.y
            newBounds.size.height = bounds.size.height
            return newBounds
        }
        
        override func routeButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            var newBounds = super.routeButtonRect(forBounds: bounds)
            newBounds.origin.y = bounds.origin.y
            newBounds.size.height = bounds.size.height
            return newBounds
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SystemVolumeView {
        SystemVolumeView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: SystemVolumeView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Then, you can use the new UIViewRepresentable (in this example VolumeSlider()) like so:

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.black.opacity(0.50))
    VolumeSlider()
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .tint(.white)
}
.frame(height: 150)
```

You'll see the VolumeSider() is now centered within the ZStack as you'd expect. I've hardcoded the height to 150 just for an example.

[image]

Comment: this works great. The routeButtonRect function is deprecated and should be replaced with volumeThumbRect. (still works the same, no warning)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly this behavior is in fact normal for a SwiftUI view. You are specifying a point height for the `VolumeSlider`. If you decrease the 128 it will not have the space between slider and bottom divider.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            VolumeSlider()
                .frame(height: 50)
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

I'll update this answer to try and make it not take up the whole space when `.frame` is removed.